# Boost Cache problem with spaces in urls

Tags: 7, caching

I have boost set up and uses the following site URL structure :

**www.website.com/postcode/suburb+name**

So sometimes the Suburb Name might have a space it in. So in that case, all urls use "+"

Now when I check the actual cache file Boost created I get :

**/cache/normal/www.website.com/postcode/suburb name**

So boost is creating the cached file, but when I visit the page I can see it isn't being used.

However, if I manually rename the cached directory to :
**/cache/normal/www.website.com/postcode/suburb+name**

(I manually replaced the directory "space" character, with the "+")

Boost will now serve up the cached file.

So is there a better way to handle urls with spaces, %20, + in it with Boost?

Comment: Try to replace the the space(' ') from your url. Noramally it is bad practice if use space in urls.

Comment: See [pathauto transliteration](https://drupal.org/node/1163118) dunno about spaces, but it eliminates a lot of characters that are tricky for Boost to serve.